# Dropwizard gauge frequency

Tags: java, dropwizard, graphite, gauge

I am using dropwizard gauge functionality in my code as following :

```
    private AtomicInteger heapUsageAfterCollectionThresholdExceeded;

       new Gauge<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer getValue() {
            return heapUsageThresholdExceeded.get();
        }
```

Now this starts pushing the value of heapUsageThresholdExceeded to graphite. I was expecting to see integer  values in graphite. But in graphite I see the value reported as a decimal point value (0.15). I have following questions:

1. Why is a integer gauge reported as a decimal value ?
2. How often does drop wizard measure/push the metric for a registered gauge ?

ref : https://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/Gauge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, it depends on the frequency at which metrics are reported. The [default frequency](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v1.3.9/dropwizard-metrics/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/metrics/MetricsFactory.java#L45) is 1 minute

You can specify the frequency in your configuration file. Eg -

```
metrics:
  reporters:
    - type: graphite
      host: localhost
      port: 2003
      prefix: example
      frequency: 1m
```